# Image Upload Without Database Table

Tags: symfony-1.4

I want to add an Image module on my symfony 1.4 applications.The purpose is that I only need a client side upload without saving the path to a database,I just want it to save in a file in web/uploads directory.Is it possible in symfony 1.4?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Put this into your controller:

```
foreach($request->getFiles() as $file)
{
    move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir') . "/uploads/" . $file['name']);
}
```